# Node.js Axios HTTP request with bearer token returning undefined

Tags: node.js, axios, token, undefined

I've seen many posts on Stack that are close to what I need, but don't fully answer my question (I'm pretty green with Node). I'm working on connecting a Twitch/[Tiltify](https://tiltify.com/) donation campaign to a Raspberry Pi via Node.js/Axios. I'd like the Pi to regularly check for new donations, then activate physical circuits (solenoid valves etc.) to be viewed live on the stream. Here's my code so far:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('URL_GOES_HERE', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer MY_TILTIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN'
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.url);
    console.log(response.data.explanation);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I assume that `MY_TILTIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN` is the access token I generated from within my Tiltify account. I'm confused, however, about what value to put in `URL_GOES_HERE`. The somewhat sparse [Tiltify API docs](https://tiltify.github.io/api/topics/authentication.html) give two possible URLS: `https://tiltify.com/oauth/authorize` and `https://tiltify.com/oauth/token`. Or am I supposed to put my bearer credentials directly into the URL of a useful request, like `https://tiltify.com/api/v3/user`? I've tried all three, and I just get `undefined undefined` in the console.

A nudge in the right direction is appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

@benstepp over on Github ultimately answered my question. Here's the code he provided:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('https://tiltify.com/api/v3/campaigns/MY_CAMPAIGN_ID/rewards', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer MY_API_TOKEN'
  }
})
  .then(response => {                       // this is an axios response object (https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema)
    //console.log(response.data);           // this is the response body from tiltify (https://tiltify.github.io/api/endpoints/campaigns-id-donations.html)
    //console.log(response.data.data);      // this is the .data property of our responses

    response.data.data.map((reward) => {
      // the name/amount of the recent donations
      console.log(`${reward.name}`)
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/authorize` endpoint is used for the Web Server OAuth Authentication Flow and User-Agent OAuth Authentication Flow.

The `/token` endpoint is used for the Username-Password OAuth Authentication Flow and the OAuth Refresh Token Process.

So first you need to get Authorized to be able to use Tiltify api. For that you need to use either of the flow

`https://tiltify.com/oauth/authorize`

`https://tiltify.com/oauth/token`

Assuming you used `token` route, you will get a response something like this:

`{ "access_token":"token", "token_type":"bearer", "refresh_token":"refresh_token" }`

Then using the `access_token` you got from the response you will call the api routes so in `URL GOES HERE` will be your api routes like

`/campaigns/:id`
`causes/:id`

with which you'll use `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` in headers

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As it turns out, I don't even need to mess with OAuth to do the simple thing I want to do. The issue had to do with a misunderstanding of the Tiltify schema. I'll post the working code in the event it helps someone else.